# androidmanifest.xml file resolves attribute entries

Tags: android

I am new to Android and started with hello world app.

I was going through AndroidManifest.xml

```
   <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
    </application>
```

I am trying to figure out where is this ic_launcher file located or has some variable mapped.

I have folder as

```
res/drawable-hdpi
res/drawable-ldpi
```

I can see all folder has ic_launcher.png file, now my question is from which folder it will pick this image.
Also, I saw there is one entry in R.java file for this name as,

```
public static final class drawable {
    public static final int ic_launcher=0x7f020000;
}
```

What is the relation between entry in R.java and AndroidManifest.xml.

Also, second line is  `android:label="@string/app_name"`
I can see in strings.xml file, there is one entry for these,

```
  <string name="app_name">MyMapLocation</string>
```

Now, where it is written in AndroidManifest.xml file(or any other place) that go and check for app_name variable entry in strings.xml file?

I am sorry to ask this basic question but want to clear doubts.

Comment: You need to do some reading first, before diving in: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/accessing-resources.html

Comment: thanks for pointing link.. let me go through it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Question is, from which folder it will pick this(ic_launcher.img) image.

It will depend on the screen size of the device, if screen size comes in LDPI icon.img of drawable-ldpi would be picked up by system at run time.

> Now, where it is written in AndroidManifest.xml file(or any other place) that go and check for app_name variable entry in strings.xml file?

@string/app_name >> @string tells xml files that go to string.xml and search for app_name there.

**Edit:-** here is what docs says about [accessing resouces](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/accessing-resources.html) via Blad0rz